# Sharepoint Calendar New Item default start time

Tags: calendar

Is there any way to change the default Start Time (just the date) for New Item's to the date that the user clicked on?  I have tried setting the start time to (none) and to Today's Date and both of them result in pre-populating it with todays date.  We will be scheduling items in the future so when a user clicks on a date in the future, I wanted the new item to default to the date the user just clicked on to add the new item. Is that possible?

My bad.....
I wanted the default for a new item to be an all day event so I added the info below to a text file and it is working but apparently it overrides the default of the start date.
I guess I have a choice of either getting the default to be all day or the default start time to be the date the user chose but not both! But at least now I know why it's not defaulting to the date the user clicks on.

```
<script src="/is/technologyservices/applicationservices/Documents/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

if (!$('span[title=All Day Event] > input').attr("checked"))
 {
  $('span[title=All Day Event] > input').click();
 }
 //hide check-box
 //$('tr:has(span[title=All Day Event])').not('tr:has(tr)').hide();

Comment: Your question is unclear, please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want if the user to change the "default Start Time" based on a New Item's Start Time selection. You may want to create an event receiver that triggers on a NewItemAdded. The logic would browse out to the specific list and update the default value. This is pseudo code, but should be mostly correct.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            //base.ItemAdded(properties);
            using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
            {
                try
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["SPList"];
                    DateTime starttime = properties.Item["Start Time"];
                    list.Fields["Start Time"].DefaultValue = starttime;
                    list.Update();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```